# Convert to datetime producing incorrect results

Tags: sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a `varchar` column value into `datetime` datatype, and I am not getting the expected result.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-09 10:22:45.214') UNION ALL 
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-09 10:22:45.215') UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-09 10:22:45.216') UNION ALL 
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-09 10:22:45.217') UNION ALL 
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-09 10:22:45.218') UNION ALL 
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-09 10:22:45.219') UNION ALL 
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-09 10:22:45.220')
```

I am getting the following results:

```
2020-01-09 10:22:45.213
2020-01-09 10:22:45.217
2020-01-09 10:22:45.217
2020-01-09 10:22:45.217
2020-01-09 10:22:45.217
2020-01-09 10:22:45.220
2020-01-09 10:22:45.220
```

I have tried running this code in both SSMS 2014 and 2017 with the same result.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here...

Comment: `datetime2` is now the recommended datetime datatype so try `DATETIME2(3)`

Comment: Using ``datetime2`` fixes it.